# Avoid clipping label in IntervalSlider?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, slider, appearance, user-interface

For custom appearances `IntervalSlider` seems to clip on the right side:

```
IntervalSlider[
 Appearance -> {"ThumbAppearance" -> {Style["[", 18], None, 
     Style["1000", 18]}}]
```

[image]

I tried changing `FrameMargins` and other relevant options, but no luck. Any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 7):

You can tweak underlying `Graphics`:

```
IntervalSlider[
   Appearance -> {"ThumbAppearance" -> {Style["[", 18], None, Style["1000", 18]}}
,  BaseStyle -> {
     GraphicsBoxOptions -> {
       PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, .1}, Automatic}
     }
   }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there any way to keep the look of Appearance->"Paired" but tweak it, by say adding labels?

Comment: @M.R. I am not aware of any straightforward method except digging in definitions and trying to replace/insert labels where needed :/

Answer (score 6):

You can also wrap the interval slider object with `Style` and use [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html) to set  `PlotRangePaddding` option values:

```
s = IntervalSlider[Appearance -> 
    {"ThumbAppearance" -> {Style["[", 18], None, Style["1000", 18]}}]

Style[#, DefaultOptions ->
   {Graphics -> PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .1}, Automatic}}] & @ s
```

[image]